# Can we solve a homogenous differential equation using the Fourier Series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example:$(x^2+1)y''−4xy'+6y=0$. Is there any way to solve it using the Fourier series?

Comment: https://www.math24.net/fourier-series-applications-differential-equations/